# Wordpress table key relationships

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am writing a Wordpress plugin extending Woocommerce that requires to store additional information about a user.

I understand that there is a separate wp_user_meta table specific to this, but I would rather use a custom table as I plan to use Wordpress/Woocommerce as an initial platform then hopefully expand to others. The data will also be queried often.

This custom table requires a single entry per user, defined by the ID in wp_user, therefore essentially being a one-to-one relationship. An example schema for the custom table is:

```
CREATE TABLE {$wpdb->prefix}custom_table (
  custom_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  custom_data varchar(200) NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES wp_users(ID),
  PRIMARY KEY (custom_id)
)
```

My question is using Wordpress, how do you ensure that the one-to-one relationship is maintained?

I know I will have to run an initial setup to create the entries in the custom table for existing users.

Other than this, are users allowed to change their ID at all in the user lifecycle? Is it a case of using registration/deletion hooks to ensure that the data in the custom table is up to date? (Or would the deletion cascade through to other tables when it happens in the wp_user table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, users can't change their IDs nor their usernames (because, well, that leads to a whole lot of issues) so you're fine in that regard.

Also, there are a few "gotchas!" you need to be aware of:

1. Your query will fail because `user_id` isn't being defined exactly the same way as the `ID` column in `wp_users`. You have: `user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL`. It should be: `user_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL`.
2. To make `user_id` sure is unique -and maintain the one-to-one relationship- you'll need to add `UNIQUE(user_id)` to your query.
3. Your table has to use the exact same [storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-engines.html). In your query, you're not defining a storage engine for it so MySQL will fallback to the default one, which might or might not be the same one used by the `wp_users` table. If it's not the same one, the query will -again- fail and your table won't be created.

Here's the revised query, assuming `wp_users` uses the MyISAM storage engine:

```
CREATE TABLE {$wpdb->prefix}custom_table (
  custom_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  custom_data varchar(200) NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES wp_users(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY KEY (custom_id),
  UNIQUE (user_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

If you want to make sure your table uses the exact same storage engine as the `wp_users` table -and you do- running this query before creating your table will tell you which one you need:

```
SELECT ENGINE 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='{$wpdb->dbname}' AND TABLE_NAME='{$wpdb->users}';
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and informative answer. A quick note, would this implementation have the cascading effect for example when users are deleted from the wp_users table? (or as stated previously it is a case of using registration/deletion hooks to ensure the relationship is maintained?

Comment: No problem. Regarding your question, adding the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause at the end of `FOREIGN KEY (...)` should delete data from deleted users automatically for you (see updated query above). Also, if my answer helped, please consider marking it as "accepted".

Comment: using `SELECT ENGINE ...` returns an integer when the query is performed, therefore the `CREATE TABLE ...` query is then stumbling. I am running this locally using MAMP atm.

Comment: How are you querying the database? Are you using the `get_results()` method from the `$wpdb` object?

Comment: thank you, was using `query()`, `get_results()` returns innoDB.

Comment: Don't worry, I suspected you were using `query()` instead of `get_results()`. It happened to me as well :P

Comment: thanks for your help, the table is successfully being added to the database now. As you can tell I'm not that experienced with SQL. I will post the version I have in a while. Is there a way of auto populating rows of the new table with the same number as those in the wp_users table, for the initial run?

Comment: It's OK, we all have to start somewhere. It's not like I'm an expert either, I've learned a thing or two from working on my plugins. To answer your question, maybe this can help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/130688/135534

Answer (score 1):

For reference the code snippet - note that checks should be in place for checking the array size etc. but this gets me in the right direction. Thank you @cabrarahector

```
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
global $wpdb;

$query = "SELECT ENGINE FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='{$wpdb->dbname}' AND TABLE_NAME='{$wpdb->users}';";
$engine = $wpdb->get_results( $query )[0]->ENGINE;

$sql = "CREATE TABLE {$wpdb->prefix}custom_table (
    custom_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    custom_data varchar(200) NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES wp_users(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (custom_id),
    UNIQUE (user_id)
) ENGINE={$engine};";

dbDelta($sql);
```

this creates the custom table in the database